# What preposition do you use with 'dilemma'?

Tags: prepositions

I want to say that at some point in my life, I had to choose between two majors for undergraduate studies. Is this sentence grammatically correct?

> I was in the dilemma of choosing between  y engineering and z engineering to study as an undergraduate student.

Or should I say

> I was in the dilemma of choosing between  y engineering and z engineering on which major to study as an undergraduate student.

Comment: "Dilemma" is usually used when talking about choosing between equally undesirable situations.  I assume that neither course of study was undesirable, so perhaps simply saying you were "facing a choice" or some such would be a more literate way of expressing your idea.

Comment: The picturesque language is "on the horns of a dilemma" ... http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/on+the+horns+of+a+dilemma

Answer (score 2):

The preposition in the first sentence is correct. Change the beginning to "I faced the dilemma of..."

Comment: He or she can say "I was faced with the dilemma of..."

"to be faced with..." is a good way of saying exactly the same you have recommended.

Comment: Hello, michael. Quite right. I was trying to get 'on the horns of a dilemma' into the correct shape. Pointless!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should avoid using the word **"dilemma"**

> A situation in which a difficult choice has to be made between two or
>   more alternatives, especially ones that are equally undesirable: he
>   wants to make money, but he also disapproves of it: Den’s dilemma in a
>   nutshell    *[(www.oxforddictionaries.)](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dilemma)*

That is what "being on the horns of a dilemma" or "facing a dilemma" implies, trying to make impossible choices.

Most people don't use dilemma in this strict sense, but if you are writing to academics they may understand it that way; or even worse as indecision.

Choose a simpler word, more direct, such as choice, or hard choice.

Comment: @JohnH apologies; missed your comment.  I'm only 8hrs late.

Comment: No worries, @Hugh - you expanded on my point nicely.

Answer (score 0):

My partner, another good way of expressing that you are in a quandary, is by using the noun **"toss-up"**. The way you construct the phrase is by saying:

> **"It is/it was a toss-up *BETWEEN/WHETHER*" (when you want to talk about
>      a quandary)**

or

> **"It is/was a toss-up *WHETHER*" (when you talk about the possibility
>      of something to happen or not to happen)**

For instance:

> "It was a toss-up between y engineering and z engineering to study as an undergraduate student"* (people would understand that YOU are in that quandary if you previously mention yourself in the situation).

or

> "It is a toss-up whether I go or stay"*

[TO TALK ABOUT A QUANDARY]

and

> *"It was a toss-up whether prices would go up or down"* 
>   [**POSSIBILITY**, **NOT** a quandary].

Check it: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+toss-up

My regards!

Answer (score 0):

Your whole sentence is a little bit awkward. Perhaps you could rephrase it to something like:

> I was torn between studying Electrical Engineering and Computer Engineering as an undergraduate student. (but of course I came to my senses and chose CE)